# Как привязать лист к ключу HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Как в `HashMap` при добавлении нового ключа создавать новый лист, который принадлежит только этому ключу, и как обращаться к нему?

Comment: `new HashMap<String, List<String>>().put("myKey", new ArrayList<>());` ?

Comment: спасибо очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

Создаеём HashMap

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Добавляем список и ключ

```
map.put("myKey", new ArrayList<>());
```

Получаем список по ключу и добаляем в него новый элемент

```
map.get("myKey").add("Hello");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @YTPChannel если помогло, слева от вопроса есть галочка :)

Comment: спасибо, но я не могу поставить оценку уровень мал

Comment: @YTPChannel не оценку, [а галку](https://i.imgur.com/iubzBja.png) :)